# Implementing an internal interface over .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting, internalsvisibleto

I had an internal interface that I needed to implement over .NET remoting to make sure only our assemblies ever called these members remotely (used InternalsVisibleTo to give access to friend assemblies). However, when I implemented the interface and built it, I got the following error:

```
'AssemblyName' does not implement interface member 'InterfaceMember1(...)' 'AssemblyName' cannot implement an interface because it is not public.
```

I was unable to search and find a way to make this work. However, I explicitly implemented the interface which allowed my assembly to build, and I can call the remote methods from any friend assembly with no issues.

I'm concerned with the lack of information I found on this topic though, especially on MSDN and StackOverflow. Is there anything wrong with implementing .NET remoting over an internal interface? And if so, why?

**EDIT**
Here is what my interface and implementation look like:

Interface

```
internal interface IAdmin
{
    bool TESTPING();
    bool AdminTask1(int val);
    ...
}
```

Implementation

```
public class RService : MarshalByRefObject, IAdmin
{
    //IAdmin members

    bool IAdmin.TESTPING()
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool IAdmin.AdminTask1(int val)
    {
        // do stuff
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement security feature that way. Remoting specification is open, so anyone can create a message, send it to your remoted class and receive a response. Your service cannot reliably determine who called it.

You can implement a custom authorization, and send a secret token with each method call to ensure that only your code calls it.

Comment: I already do this in my code, I thought making the interface internal might add a bit of extra security which it seems is not the case

Answer (score 1):

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182313(VS.80).aspx

> Interface methods have public
>   accessibility, which cannot be changed
>   by the implementing type. An internal
>   interface creates a contract that is
>   not intended to be implemented outside
>   the assembly that defines the
>   interface. A public type that
>   implements a method of an internal
>   interface using the virtual modifier
>   allows the method to be overridden by
>   a derived type that is outside the
>   assembly. If a second type in the
>   defining assembly calls the method and
>   expects an internal-only contract,
>   behavior might be compromised when,
>   instead, the overridden method in the
>   outside assembly is executed. This
>   creates a security vulnerability.

Comment: Isn't the bit about having the interface member overridden only true if I mark the interface members as virtual? I thought interface members were sealed by default in .NET? Or am I misunderstanding the vulnerability?

Comment: An interface is always abstract. The MSDN article is talking about creating a class, which implements the interface and sets the implemented members as virtual. And in your remote application, you inherit from the new class. But before doing this, I would think about making the interface public.